# How to install boost 1.53 or 1.54 from terminal?

Tags: apt, gcc, g++

I'd like to install boost 1.53 or 1.54 from terminal in Ubuntu 12.04. How do I do this? I used the libboost command and it gave me 1.48, whereas I need a more recent version.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you need boost (or libboost) 1.53, **you must use Saucy**. Boost before raring only goes until 1.49 while in Saucy you get 1.53. [Trusty is in Pre-Pre-Alpha (can brick at any moment) and apparently will have 1.54.](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libboost)

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the possibly-dumb question, but how do I get/use/install boost from saucy?

Comment: @user997112 `sudo apt-get install libboost-dev`?

Comment: Ok I have just done some googling- I didnt realise Saucy was the name for an Ubuntu version. I am on 12.10- is there an easy way to upgrade to 13.10/saucy via the terminal without losing anything? (I dont want to lose my gcc4.8 and g++4.8 configs etc).

Comment: Upgrade to raring, then upgrade to saucy. That's the only way.

Comment: NMV - found it at http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libboost-dev